# Data not being returned from the rest service when using @Transactional

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-data-jpa, h2

I have created a sample hotel reservation application 
I have 2 services one is Booking service and the other is for viewing bookings, I am using in memory DB H2.

when I try to book a room using booking URL of the booking service , the Booking happens(returns 200 OK) but the data for the booking is not returned when I am using `@Transactional`. It works fine if i remove `@Transactional` (returns 200 OK and also the booking data )

`BookingServiceImpl`

```
    package com.reservation.hotel.service.impl;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import com.reservation.hotel.data.repositories.ReservationRepository;
import com.reservation.hotel.data.repositories.RoomRepository;
import com.reservation.hotel.domain.RoomReservation;
import com.reservation.hotel.domain.entities.Reservation;
import com.reservation.hotel.domain.entities.Room;
import com.reservation.hotel.service.BookingService;

@Service

public class BookingServiceImpl implements BookingService{

    @Autowired
    ReservationRepository reservationRepository;

    @Autowired
    RoomRepository roomRepository;

    private static final DateFormat DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    private static final String getReservationsByGuestIdURL = "http://localhost:8088/hotel/reservations/guest/";

    @Transactional
    public List<RoomReservation> bookRoom(String roomId, String guestId, String date){
        //List<RoomReservation> reservations= new ArrayList<>();    


        //change status of booked room to true      
        Optional<Room> room = roomRepository.findById(Long.parseLong(roomId));      
        room.get().setBooked(true);     
        roomRepository.save(room.get());        

        Reservation reservation = new Reservation();

        reservation.setGuestId(Long.parseLong(guestId));
        reservation.setRoomId(Long.parseLong(roomId));
        reservation.setDate(new java.sql.Date(createDateFromDateString(date).getTime()));

        reservationRepository.save(reservation);

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

        return restTemplate.getForObject(getReservationsByGuestIdURL + guestId, List.class);

    }

    private Date createDateFromDateString(String dateString){
        Date date = null;
        if(null!=dateString) {
            try {
                date = DATE_FORMAT.parse(dateString);
            }catch(ParseException pe){
                date = new Date();
            }
        }else{
            date = new Date();
        }
        return date;
    }



}
```

I am getting an empty response when using `@Transactional` for

```
return restTemplate.getForObject(getReservationsByGuestIdURL + guestId, List.class);
```

Can you please explain what is going on here ?

Comment: You're sending a HTTP request to your own application to get some value and return it, but the value hasn't been saved yet to the database, since the transaction is not committed yet. I have absolutely no idea why you're doing that instead of just querying your database directly.

Comment: i plan to to break down this into a micro services application later , I am trying to follow Command Query Responsibility Segregation (CQRS) pattern.

Comment: JB is it possible to stop the method from returning until the transaction is complete . what could be the alternative if i want i don't want to duplicate the fetch code again Also how do i point the user to booking results in such a scenario? any thoughts on this highly appreciated

Comment: You shouldn't duplicate the fetch code. You should call the same method from both web services is you really want to return the data in the body of your POST response (which you should normally not do: you should return the ID/URL of the created resource, and the client should send a second GET request to obtain the resource).

Comment: Ok i got your answer,  I think I am going to do  a little more digging how this will be done in a microservices env where each service is suppose to have its own  DB, Thanks :)